# Exception constructor with Exception Java

Tags: java, exception, inheritance, constructor

Does anybody know why for the overriding process the overriding method must throw an Exception of the same type (or subtype) of the overridden method whereas on the other hand for constructors it work the other way around (hence, must throw the same Exception or a supertype of what the   superclass threw.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: That's not true. So the question doesn't make sense. A subclass constructor doesn't override its superclass constructor. It calls it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructors don't override their superclass's constructor, but they do *call* a superclass constructor, either explicitly or implicitly. So, just as a method which calls some other method which throws an `Exception`, the constructor must either catch the exception thrown by the superclass's constructor or it must declare that it throws that same exception (or a superclass of that exception).

An overriding method, on the other hand, must adhere to the superclass's method definition. As such, it can throw a more specific exception or none at all. But it cannot throw a broader exception, as that would violate the superclass's contract.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there are no such restrictions on subclass constructors.  They can throw any type of Exception they care to, unrelated to the types thrown by superclass constructors.  Obviously if they let an exception from the superclass constructor through, they would have to declare it or a supertype of it, just as with any other method.  This is not a specific restriction to subclass constructors though: you could just as easily catch and handle the exception by throwing some other type.

Reason why is that a constructor in a subclass doesn't 'override' a constructor in the superclass, and isn't used polymorphically in the way.  It's an independent thing, just like a a function called `Subclass.B()` is independent from `Superclass.A()`.

Further you *always* know that when you call `new Subclass()`, you're calling that constructor.  Whereas if you have a reference to a `Superclass`, and call `superclass.overriddenMethod()` on it, you can't be sure what the type is.  Therefore, any subclasses that override that method can't throw exceptions other than those declared on the superclass, any more than they could change the rest of the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor there is always a (possibly implicit) call of super.
Throwing a super class Exception will catch that too.

```
public B() {
    ... initialize fields declared with X x = ...;
    ... call super constructor
    ... body of constructor
}
```

An overriding method however can be more specific, also for the exceptions: reduce the possibilities.